# Direct network traffic through one connection+proxy, except for a whitelist

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, routing

**How can I direct traffic to certain sites** (`https://drive.google.com`, `https://www.npmjs.com`,…) **through one network connection** (“whitelist”), **while all else through another?**

**Ugly extra:**The latter requires a proxy (for all http and https traffic), the former does not. ( Ubuntu-MATE 16.04 )

---

Using `ifconfig` I seem to have several network adapters (hoping that's the right term). I switched them on and off to diff the text outputs (`ifconfig >out.txt`) and learned that...

> **enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:97:...**

...seems to be always around. And has no "inet addr". As well as `lo` which has `inet addr:127.0.0.1`, so I guess that's localhost and can be ignored.

> **wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:06:... inet addr:192.168....**

...appears to be my wifi.

> **enp0s29u1u8u3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:00:... net addr:10.50....**

...appears to be my mobile connection (tethered through a mobile device via USB). Whitelist should go through this one.

---

**`ip route` ouput:**

```
default via 10.50.xxx.x dev wlp3s0  proto static  metric 600
10.49.xxx.xxx via 10.50.xxx.x dev wlp3s0  proto dhcp  metric 600
10.50.xxx.x/23 dev wlp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.50.241.119  metric 600
169.xxx.x.x/16 dev wlp3s0  scope link  metric 1000
```

---

Command Line is fine. But if there was a tool to do such finer-grained adjustments, I'd be happy, too :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, then you are making your life harder than it needs to be.  It's actually your "ugly extra" which makes this simple: you are not looking for network routing, but for http/https proxying.

Just define a manual proxy (via the network settings panel), and put the domain names you want to "whitelist" in the exceptions.  This will make the non-proxied URLs go through your default gateway (see output of `ip route`), and the proxied ones via the proxy.

Comment: I am afraid: no. Not going through proxy is not enough. Must go through the other network connection.

Comment: @FrankNocke Please add the output of `ip route` to your question.

Comment: done, above ...

Comment: @FrankNocke I don't see any routes for the `192.168` network you mention? I also see just a single interface `wlp3s0`, connecting to the internet via exactly one  route. Setting a proxy and whitelisting the exceptions will achieve just what you're looking for. If you are convinced this is not the case, then please be more specific and precise: what is the IP address of the proxy, and what are the networks you are connected to? Note: no need to black out addresses in the 10.x and 192.168.x ranges, as they are by definition accessible only from within your LAN.